# R text automation function

Tags: r

Basically I created a function that creates monthly employee files. However, I would like this to be automated for say 24 consecutive months.

Is there a way to automate this and automatically appends the monthly file into 1 "master file"?

Code below: (3 months did it manually....)

```
employee <- function(date1inp)
{
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
tenure_start_date <- c('2016-01-31','2015-06-30','2015-09-30')
mis_date <- c(date1inp)  
data <- data.frame(mis_date,tenure_start_date,employee,salary)
data$tenure <- as.Date(data$mis_date) - as.Date(data$tenure_start_date)
data$salarynew <- (data$tenure/365) * data$salary

return(data)
}

employee_20161231 <- employee(c("2016-12-31"))
employee_20170131 <- employee(c("2016-01-31"))
employee_20170228 <- employee(c("2017-02-28"))

employee_total <- rbind(employee_20161231,employee_20170131,employee_20170228)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of `seq`(`.Date` implied), an `lapply`, and `do.call(rbind, ...)` will do the trick. Using your `employee` function and demonstrating a year of "1sts":

```
d <- as.Date("2016-01-01")
seq(d, d + 365, by = "month")
#  [1] "2016-01-01" "2016-02-01" "2016-03-01" "2016-04-01" "2016-05-01"
#  [6] "2016-06-01" "2016-07-01" "2016-08-01" "2016-09-01" "2016-10-01"
# [11] "2016-11-01" "2016-12-01"
lst <- lapply(seq(d, d + 365, by = "month"), employee)
lst[[5]]
#     mis_date tenure_start_date   employee salary   tenure      salarynew
# 1 2016-05-01        2016-01-31   John Doe  21000  91 days  5235.616 days
# 2 2016-05-01        2015-06-30 Peter Gynn  23400 306 days 19617.534 days
# 3 2016-05-01        2015-09-30 Jolie Hope  26800 214 days 15712.877 days
results <- do.call("rbind", lst)
head(results, n = 7)
#     mis_date tenure_start_date   employee salary   tenure        salarynew
# 1 2016-01-01        2016-01-31   John Doe  21000 -30 days -1726.02740 days
# 2 2016-01-01        2015-06-30 Peter Gynn  23400 185 days 11860.27397 days
# 3 2016-01-01        2015-09-30 Jolie Hope  26800  93 days  6828.49315 days
# 4 2016-02-01        2016-01-31   John Doe  21000   1 days    57.53425 days
# 5 2016-02-01        2015-06-30 Peter Gynn  23400 216 days 13847.67123 days
# 6 2016-02-01        2015-09-30 Jolie Hope  26800 124 days  9104.65753 days
# 7 2016-03-01        2016-01-31   John Doe  21000  30 days  1726.02740 days
```

Note that doing a year of "last day of month"s is not as straight-forward as you may like:

```
d <- as.Date("2016-01-31")
seq(d, d + 365, by = "month")
#  [1] "2016-01-31" "2016-03-02" "2016-03-31" "2016-05-01" "2016-05-31"
#  [6] "2016-07-01" "2016-07-31" "2016-08-31" "2016-10-01" "2016-10-31"
# [11] "2016-12-01" "2016-12-31"
```

One trick is to take the "1st of the month"s and subtract one:

```
d <- as.Date("2016-02-01")
seq(d, d + 365, by = "month") - 1
#  [1] "2016-01-31" "2016-02-29" "2016-03-31" "2016-04-30" "2016-05-31"
#  [6] "2016-06-30" "2016-07-31" "2016-08-31" "2016-09-30" "2016-10-31"
# [11] "2016-11-30" "2016-12-31"
```